# Change Value of TextView, ImageView, ImageButton when i press button in other Activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, textview, imageview

I am developing one simple app but i have problem.

The problem I have is that two activities, Activity1, have 26 button A-Z and Activity2 have textView,ImageView. I don't know how to set the button with default value.

#### Question

How can I change the value of textView, ImageView, and button in Activity2 whenever I press any button in Activity1?

[image]

#### Question

if i click buttonA how can i change texView display from "TextView" to "A" and imageView to other Image can u guys help me?

Comment: can you post Activity1,Activity2 code here ..?

Comment: i edit my question sir can u help me

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you can pass the value within intent like

```
Intent Activity2Intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
Activity2Intent.putExtra("BUTTON_TEXT", yourText);
Activity2Intent.putExtra("IMAGE_VIEW", yourText);
startActivity(Activity2Intent);
```

Else if the data is needed later you can store that in `SqliteDatabase`

**UPDATE**

You should also need to extract the values passed from the bundle on `Activity2`.

Comment: Alternatively you can use SharedPreferences for saving the required values.

Comment: Cause, in addition to @Arju 's code, you need to get your extras from your second activity. 
Intent intent = getIntent();
String buttonText = intent.getStringExtra("BUTTON_TEXT");
String imgTxt = intent.getStringExtra("IMAGE_VIEW");
//Update your text view with these variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences` or `Intent` for passing the value from `Activity A` and retrive the value in next Activity .

In Activity A:::

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do something and save the value and pass it using intent 
// pass the button name or use boolean is_state= true;



            }
        });
```

In Activity B:::

By using `getIntent() retrive the button name and change the`TextView`and`ImageView` as per your requirement